# java.lang.SecurityException request codes from

Tags: android

while i run my one android application, i got below issue:

```
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.chinamobile.cmi.jego/com.chinamobile.cmi.jego.ui.activity.HomeGroupActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Requesting code from com.chinamobile.cmi.jego (with uid 10079)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:2806)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:2851)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1164)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Requesting code from com.chinamobile.cmi.jego (with uid 10079)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.getPackageInfo(ActivityThread.java:1582)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1852)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1797)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.dispatchStop(LocalActivityManager.java:577)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at android.app.ActivityGroup.onStop(ActivityGroup.java:82)
03-07 18:50:01.485 E/AndroidRuntime( 1344):     at com.chinamobile.cmi.jego.ui.activity.HomeGroupActivity.onStop(HomeGroupActivity.java:452)
```

(HomeGroupActivity) is an activitygroup, and there are three local activities in it.
anyone got the same issue? Could you help me?

Comment: Are you trying to access Activites from outside your app?

Comment: Can you post OnStop() function ?

Comment: all of the activites are in my local app, and In the HomeGroupActivity.java, i also overrided onStop function.

Comment: I researched android4.0.3 source code. the exception comes from below     if ((flags&(Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE
    |Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY))
    == Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE) {
    if (securityViolation) {
    String msg = "Requesting code from " +   ai.packageName+ " (with uid " + ai.uid + ")";

Comment: I have seen this happened to me a few times too among thousands of app sessions. Seems to happen only on 4.0.3.